# How to send daily reminders/email alerts before event start date

Tags: email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

I have created a custom object "Assigned tasks" that works like tasks such that it has due date, status, subject, priority e.t.c. This custom object "Assigned tasks" is a child object to case object. Case object has a date/time field called "Event start date".

I want to send daily email alerts/reminders for the pending tasks(status=pending) starting from 20 days left to event execution until the event day. So in total 20 reminders, each on one day. I know there is an option to schedule email alert through time-based workflows, but I don't seem to find any option that says daily, it either says 'num of days' 'before' or 'after' a particular date. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a field in `Assigned task` object called `Reminder Date`.

When the record is created then update `Reminder Date` as = `Event Start Date - 20` with workflow field update.

Create a workflow rule based on `Event Start Date > Reminder Date` with other criteria like status is not closed.

Create a time-dependent workflow like `1 hour after Reminder Date`. Here you will send an email and most importantly, update `Reminder Date` field to next date.

System will compares the dates and every day until Event Start Date it will send reminders.

Flow will look like this:

[image: Flow]

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining the answer in detail. It really helped. The only thing I am concerned is that I tried making today the 20th day, so it sent me an email alert but then when I go and check the time-based workflow section, it doesn't show anything scheduled for tomorrow? I know it does and will trigger on 20th day but will it also trigger on 19th, 18th e.t.c day as well because apparently the criteria would not change on 19th day, which is task should be pending and event start date > reminder date, so would it still trigger the email alert?

Comment: Ahhh ok I guess when updating the reminder field to increase by 1, I need to select the 'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change' checkbox.